# Integrating a windows form in OutLookAddIn project and calling the OutLookAddIn class form winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-addin

Im working on a OutLookAddIn Project and for a particualr scenario i added a winform to the outllookaddin project, so when the user first loads the project the winform opens up...After entering his UserId and Password and clicking the submit button i want to call a method that is in the class 'ThisAddIn' but im not able to access the method from windows form class, im getting the error as ''OutlookAddIn1.ThisAddIn' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments''....how can i get rid of this...just posting some sample code below

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace OutlookAddIn1
    {
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {



    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    public void Validate()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }



    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

My Winform class from where i want to access the method 'Validate'

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Drawing;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Windows.Forms;


  namespace OutlookAddIn1
  {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
   }
  }
```

In the button1_Click event i want t0 access the method validate, so need some advice from experts here..

Comment: Do the following: ThisAddin ta = new ThisAddin(); ta.Validate(); put this code in the button1_Click event.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following, first create a new instance of the `ThisAddin class`, then call the `Validate method` in the `ThisAddin class` from the new `created instance`.

**Change:**

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

**To:**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ThisAddin ta = new ThisAddin();
                ta.Validate();
            }
        }
```

**Change the ThisAddin class from:**

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {



    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    public void Validate()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
    //constructor
    public ThisAddin()
    {

    }


    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Validate()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

**Note:**

Make sure the classes are placed in the same `Namespace:
[Namespaces description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: this was the first approach what i tired, but the issue here is a compile time error ''OutlookAddIn1.ThisAddIn' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments''.....struggling from 6 hrs to resolve this so finally posted it here so that i could get some help

Comment: This should work, because you aren't sending any parameters to the Validate method, and the Validate method doesn't require any. Are you sure that you are calling the correct Validate method? Can you try right clicking Validate in the button1_click event, and then chose: "Go to definition" if you are directed to the right "Validate" method, it should be good to go..

Comment: the first issue here is im not able to create the instance of the class 'ThisAddIn'...when in type ThisAddIn th=new ThisAddIn();..im getting the compilation error as 'OutlookAddIn1.ThisAddIn' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'...

Comment: Ah I think I get it, is your ThisAddin class in the same namespace? it's right above the 'public partial class' text.

Comment: yesss , both my ThisAddin class and Form1 class are in the same name space OutlookAddIn1..

Comment: Add following code at top in form class: using OutlookAddIn1.Form1;

Comment: when n type OutlookAddIn1 im getting only properties in the intellisense in the form1 class?

Comment: Can you edit your question, with full code from classes, would help me a lot solving your problem.

Comment: done, edited my question..there is nothing mystery in the issue...the class 'ThisAddIn' is not having a contructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Ah wait, check my answer, I inserted a constructor for your class, this should work.

Comment: i tried even that, even this gives compilation error 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.OutlookAddInBase' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'......i dont know where is this base class?

Comment: Can you try to create a new windows form application using my code, I'm sure that works, are you implementing the Office tools the correct way?

Comment: even that did not work....when i created the constructor im able to call the validate method from form1 class but the compilation error now shifts to ThisAddIn class......'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.OutlookAddInBase' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'.

Comment: yesss.....thats inbuilt base class and when i view that class from gotodefinition...that takes me to that class and its metadata class and im not able to edit it

Comment: hmm, thats a whole different story, you could check out the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx